# How to setup the react native navigation on android?

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native, react-native-navigation

I have some issue with WIX react native navigation when I installed them,
I'm doing the steps in the documentation correctly but when running the app and Configure the libs and when up to Configure react native vector icon,
I have **" Build Failed ".**

```
> Configure project :react-native-vector-icons
The CompileOptions.bootClasspath property has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 5.0. Please use the CompileOptions.bootstrapClasspath property instead.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithExternalLibsDexMergerForDebug'.
> java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.builder.dexing.DexArchiveMergerException: Unable to merge dex Unable to merge dex
```

so I don't Know what's wrong,
please if you have the same issue and fixed them, help me

Comment: I do not know about wix, but I have managed navigation succesfully and declaratory with react-router

Comment: @Jumper I am forced to use it sadly

Comment: There is an issue thread on the repo for react-native-vector-icons that suggests using an older version of the Gradle plugin: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14.1-all.zip`

Comment: but the WIX use the last version : distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
!! how to solve the confused of this!

Comment: also, are you using RNN v1? you might consider switching to v2

Comment: No, im using v2,   "react-native-navigation": "^2.8.0"

Comment: another issue thread that might be helpful: https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3419 it looks like this may be caused by the app-level support libraries being out of date

Answer (score 0):

For navigation between screens and Routing and navigation for your React Native apps you can switch to React Navigation 3x https://reactnavigation.org/. Its an extensible yet easy-to-use navigation solution written entirely in JavaScript (so you can read and understand all of the source), on top of powerful native primitives.

If you're already familiar with React Native then you'll be able to get moving with React Navigation quickly!

Install the react-navigation package in your React Native project.

`yarn add react-navigation`

or with npm

`npm install --save react-navigation`

Next, install react-native-gesture-handler. If you’re using Expo you don’t need to do anything here, it’s included in the SDK. Otherwise:

`yarn add react-native-gesture-handler`

or with npm

`npm install --save react-native-gesture-handler`

Link all native dependencies:

`react-native link react-native-gesture-handler`

No additional steps are required for iOS.

To finalise installation of `react-native-gesture-handler` for Android, be sure to make the necessary modifications to `MainActivity.java`:

```
package com.reactnavigation.example;

import com.facebook.react.ReactActivity;
import com.facebook.react.ReactActivityDelegate;
import com.facebook.react.ReactRootView;
import com.swmansion.gesturehandler.react.RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView;

public class MainActivity extends ReactActivity {

  @Override
  protected String getMainComponentName() {
    return "Example";
  }

  @Override
  protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
    return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
      @Override
      protected ReactRootView createRootView() {
       return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);
      }
    };
  }
}
```

You're good to go!

Comment: sorry but if I try to run reat-native run android i have this build problem: 24: error: cannot find symbol return new RNGestureHandlerEnabledRootView(MainActivity.this);    how can I fix it?

Comment: it is very important to follow each and every step followed by the next step. the above-given answer is the correct method for installation. please follow it in correct order to solve your issue @HouseFragance